# responsive horizontal site to vertical scrolling trouble

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently building a fullscreen one page responsive site. The desktop version should be horizontal scrolling and when screen size changes to say, under 800px, it should change into vertical layout.

ie.

`Size > 800 -->    Page1 | Page2 | Page3`

```
Size < 800 -->   Page1     
                 Page2
                 Page3
```

I've tried building mobile-first way, and change the layout from vertical to horizontal using `media query` and `display: inline block` with `white-space: nowrap`.

It works, but when I test using Google F12 Feature Toggle Device Mode, and change to wide sizes, I notice that I could scroll way down past over the horizontal layout, as if there is something that overflow in y-axis. (it should overflow x-axis at this size, not y).

Setting the body/html to overflow hidden prevent any scrolling (horizontal/vertical) and that's not what I want...

Can anyone help me? I'm new in building responsive site especially with this type of layout. So a link to a good tutorial, advice, or better yet, answer to my problem, is very welcome :)

(PS: I work locally, so I don't really know if putting the code in codepen would actually recreate the problem I had)

some codepen test: http://codepen.io/ayakashi/pen/rVzpvG

**UPDATE**: it seems to be working fine in real devices, so maybe it's just how it supposed to be when checking with browsers' device mode feature....

Comment: I'm having a hard time replicating the issue. Could you clarify "wide sizes"? Or give some more exact values?

Comment: well, i tried google nexus 10.

Comment: i tried replicating my issue in codepen, but it seems it works fine in codepen. i tried various wide sizes (above 1100px) and it's fine. but when i tried my local work files, the problem appear.

Comment: it's as if the height from the vertical layout is still affecting the horizontal layout (causing the overflow-y) even though in horizontal layout the sections already changed into `inline-block`s...

Comment: oh and i tried in firefox "responsive mode" and it's fine and same problem appear in opera webkit. So, it seems the problem appear in webkit browsers.

Comment: If I copy the CodePen over to a file, would the issue show?

Comment: Yeah, I believe so. (I tried copied the codepen into files and it's showing the same problem in webkit.)

Comment: Seems to work fine here. Did you try another pc as well? If so, could you try to share the code through git or something (GitHub, GitLab, etc...)?

Comment: actually, yes, but only the local one. I'm gonna try both code in another pc and maybe check again for any weird markup or overriding style that may causes this problem. I'll post the result as soon as i'm able. thanks for helping me, BillyNate :D

Comment: so, on real devices my page seems ok. (although it still showing the same problem in all the PC i've tried). thanks for helping me, tho' :)